# Prevent old css file to disturb bootstrap navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a finished (old) page and now I want to add a bootstrap navbar.

The first step was, to set a wrapper in the bootstrap style file to not disturb the old website.
That is done by less and work great.

But the other problem is, that the css files of the old website disturbs the css of the navbar.

The navbar is included like this:

```
<div id="navbar-wrapper">
    -- navbar --
</div>
```

The bootstrap.less file like:

```
#navbar-wrapper { 
    -- all bootstrap things ---
}
```

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Zoker/ek7chqvu/)

Is there a way to prevent the other css file to disturb the navbar (changing the old css or including the navbar via iframe is no solution for me)

Comment: can you post the code in fiddle, there is a option to add bootstrap.css

Comment: I copied the less compilied bootstrap file calles bootstrap-less.css:
http://jsfiddle.net/Zoker/ek7chqvu/

Here you can see the issue

Comment: 1) I would make sure that all the navbar classes are properly being "scoped" by your id and 2) more importantly, the specificity of your old stylesheet is probably leaking into your navbar styles even if you've properly "scoped" the bootstrap styles.

Comment: Is hiding the old code in comments a possibilty?

Comment: No because the old page, needs the old css, so I cant comment it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have old CSS leaking into your new CSS. From your jsFiddle I can see that `common.css` has the class `.dropdown` defined in it which is also defined in Bootstrap's CSS. This is what is breaking your layout. You will need to reset or undo what the earlier definition of `.dropdown` is defining to fix the display issues you are having.

Example, per your jsFiddle:

```
#mainNavbar .dropdown {
    position: static;
    left: auto;
    top: auto;
    z-index: auto;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Updated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ek7chqvu/2/

**NOTE:** the CSS id `#mainNavbar` is not required if the "reset" `.dropdown` class is defined after the `.dropdown` class defined in `common.css`.

Comment: Works great :)
Can you tell my, why there is no bootstrap style in the bar?
I dont mean the structure, I mean something like the color...

Comment: If your talking about the font size, color and background color of the navbar items, then it is the same issue. The font size is being set by `body` in `common.css` on line 59, background color is set by `.navbar`in `colour.css` on line 57 and it looks like the link color you have set yourself with `#mainNavbar a`. Does that clear anything up?

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) The problem was, that I had the id directly in the navbar and there for a #mainNvabar .navbar could not change the style of the navbar. So I just wrapped the navbar with that id.